# Solving an equation $z + |z|^2 = 10 - 2i$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do you solve the equation $z+ |z|^2 = 10 - 2i$ and express the solution in the form $a+bi$?

I feel like this should be easy but I'm having a blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $z=a+ib$ and extract two equations for the real part and imaginary part. Solve for a and b.

Edit:

$|z|^2+z=10-2i$, we get:

$a^2+b^2+a+ib=10-2i$, hence

$a^2+b^2+a+ib-10+2i=0$

$a^2+b^2+a-10+i(b+2)=0$, therefore the two equations

I. $a^2+b^2+a-10=0$ which is the real part and

II. $b+2=0$ which is the imaginary part.

From II. we get $b=-2$ immediately and can use it in I.
This gives us:

$a^2+a+4-10=0$

$a^2+a-6=0$ use a formula for quadratic equations, or see the solutions immediately, since

$a^2+a-6=(a+3)(a-2)=0$ therefore we get two solutions for $a$ namley $a_1=-3$ and $a_2=2$

And we are done.

Comment: Thanks. You went above and beyond solving the equation but it was a big help in terms of visualising the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Determine the real part and the imaginary part of the equation and assume $z=a+bi$:

$$\operatorname{Re}(z)+|z|^2=10\implies a+a^2+b^2=10$$

$$\operatorname{Im}(z)=-2 \implies b=-2$$

From the first equation, you can determine $a$. Note, that I implicitly used that $|z|^2\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As a streamlined version of this, we can write the initial equation as $z=10-2i+|z|^2$; since $|z|^2$ is positive real, the imaginary part of $z$ must be $-2$. After that one just has a real quadratic.

Comment: Thanks for the method. I think what happened is that the |z|^2 threw me off. But changing it to get a quadratic and solving to get the values made sense.

Answer (score 1):

let $$z=x+iy$$ then your equation is
$$x+iy+x^2+y^2=10-2i$$ and you will get the System
$$x+x^2+y^2=10$$
$$y=-2$$